# Cocoa-Bindings : Bind NSComboBox selection to a field in NSObjectController

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nscombobox

in my application I have a NSObjectController bound to all controls on the user interface. This works fine so far. The only problem I have is binding the selection of an NSComboBox to the same ObjectController. As far as I found out today the value of a ComboBox is always a string so the field in the Class of the OBjectController is also an NSString.Sounds easy for me but doesn't work.

I always get an "**... class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ...**"

The items in the ComboBox itself come from an other Controller, a NSArrayController. But that part works fine. All the items from the Array are items in the ComboBox. The Problem I have is getting the selection into to ObjectController.

Comment: Please post the full exception message.

Answer (score 2):

It's just saying that whatever data-model object that NSObjectController is using does't have an appropriate key method for that value.

From looking at the Cocoa Bindings Reference documentation, the `value` binding should be set to a key in your NSObjectController that corresponds to a key-value-coding compliant key in its model.

Example:

`NSObjectController` mode is `Class`, Class Name is `foo`.  Then you bind foo's key of `comboSelection` to the NSComboBox's `value`.  What the exception is saying is that the Foo class doesn't have a method called `comboSelection`:

```
- (NSString*)comboSelection;
- (void)setComboSelection:(NSString*)inSelection;
```

In the case of using a NSMutableDictionary as the NSObjectController's class, it's much easier, since the dictionary can hold arbitrary keys.

If you're using CoreData (mode = Entity), then your CoreData entity must contain the appropriate property.